# R - apply function to data frames serially

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I have dataframe mydf and I've split it to get number of data frames like  `mydf$'1' mydf$'2'...mydf$'n'`.
I wish to apply my function on these data frames to get resultdf like

```
resultdf1 <- myfunc(mydf$'1')
resultdf2 <- myfunc(mydf$'2')
.....
resultdfn <- myfunc(mydf$'n')
```

and so on...Since there are about 35 data frames from the split. How can I reduce my effort without manually writing for each frame name and resultdf.

I tried lapply but didn't work out correctly.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What didn't work out correctly?  Please show what you tried and the output.

Comment: Don't have sequentially named variables - [use a list of data frames](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `split` on a data frame should give you a list of smaller data frames.  So perhaps it would just make sense to call `lapply` on this split list, e.g.

```
mydf.split <- split(mydf, mydf$col)
list.result <- lapply(mydf.split, function(x) { /* do something */ })
```

The above would yield another list, with each node containing the result of your function.  If you want to get back a vector instead, you could use `sapply`.  For example, if you wanted the number of rows in each of your split data frames, you could do

```
mydf.counts <- sapply(mydf.split, function(x) nrow(x))
```

Comment: And after that you can bind.rows from dplyr on list to get 1 data frame.

Comment: @M.Siwik if you're using `dplyr`, why would you even split in the first place? Just `group_by`...

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to write something as function in lapply on list of dataframes than using group_by for me;)

Comment: This was good...I was overly concerned with naming in the split frame and result frame.